# Run kill command from sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to kill the active session in the following way...

```
C:\>sqlcmd -E -S %COMPUTERNAME%\INSTANCE -Q "kill (SELECT session_id FROM sys
.dm_exec_sessions WHERE login_name = 'dbuser')"
```

How to make it work...

Comment: Did you get some information message? error?

Comment: @Phx Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server ###, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Did you try that command on Sql Server Management Studio? Is not correct. Try to build a correct sql command and check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KILL requires a session id literal so you need to build and execute a script with the needed KILL commands.  The method below will also handle multiple sessions.

```
sqlcmd -E -S . -Q "DECLARE @KillCommands nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT 'KILL ' + CAST(session_id AS varchar(5)) + ';' FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE login_name = 'dbuser' FOR XML PATH(''));EXEC(@KillCommands);"
```